# Invoke Safari protocol

Tags: mobile-safari, protocols

Is it possible to invoke mobile-safari by protocol like

```
safari://my.site
```

From pseudobrowser safari, when it popup after select network with page "Log In" ?

When i select network from my network list in IPad or IPhone i see "Log in" pseudo-safari-browser-window-without-tabs with html code. I wish to redirect from that page to normal safari-browser like if i have installed google chrome. `window.location=googlechrome://my.site`

Comment: invoke from where? I don't think you can open any application by specifying it as a protocol though :)

Comment: When i select network from my network list in IPad or IPhone i see *Log in* pseudo-safari-browser-window-without-tabs with html code. I wish to redirect from that page to normal safari-browser like if i have installed google chrome.
window.location=googlechrome://my.site